# Check if array 1 has all the letters of array 2

Tags: php, arrays

I've got this 2 variables that I want to compare on a certain way. So I already figured out that I have to put it in a array and compare them that way. But there's the problem.

If my input is 'rieebbb', random sequence.
And my other input is 'beer' as in, the word beer.

How do I check if the letters in beer are all in 'rieebbb' and that I all use them once?
So 'riebbb' shouldn't give a positive answer because I am missing a 'e' in the random sequence.

I've already tried array_intersect() but that did'nt totaly work because it didn't check for letters already used in array 1.

Comment: Somebody's making a scrabble helper...

Comment: That's pretty straightforward to do if you convert each string to a `letter => frequency` map.

Comment: @FelixKling Damn..That's exactly what I suggested :P Or is it that obvious? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a frequency match..count the occurrence of each character in say "beer" and store that in an array A.

That would be {{b,1},{e,2},{r,1})..

Do the same on your target string.

Compare the two arrays for the letters in the array A.
That should solve it.

Here's the code for the same:

```
<?php
$data = "beer";

$data2="rebe";
$p=0;
$q=0;
$stat=0;
foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val)   
{
  $arr1[$p][0]=chr($i);
  $arr1[$p][1]=$val;
  $p=$p+1;
}
foreach (count_chars($data2, 1) as $j => $val2) 
{
    $arr2[$q][0]=chr($j);
    $arr2[$q][1]=$val2;     
    $q=$q+1;
}

for($st=0;$st<$q;$st=$st+1)
{
        for($sp=0;$sp<$p;$sp=$sp+1)
        {
            if($arr2[$st][0]==$arr1[$sp][0])
            {
                    if($arr2[$st][1]<$arr1[$sp][1])
                    {
                            $stat=1;
                    }
            }
    }
}
if($stat==0)
{
echo "They match";
}
     else
{
 echo "They dont match";
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok, that helped me a lot but now I'm stuck while comparing them. array_intersect_assoc() doesn't do what I want but I can't figure out what will...

Comment: Ummm...brute force ! A nested for loop..do u really need the Code??? And don't think just in terms of the built-in functions..that can only take you so far..

Comment: Here's your code <?php
$data = "beer";

$data2="rieebbb";
$p=0;
$q=0;
$stat=0;
foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val) 
{
   $arr1[$p][0]=chr($i);
   $arr1[$p][1]=$val;
   $p=$p+1;
}
foreach (count_chars($data2, 1) as $j => $val2) 
{
        $arr2[$q][0]=chr($j);
 $arr2[$q][1]=$val2; 
 $q=$q+1;
}

for($st=0;$st<$q;$st=$st+1)
{
 for($sp=0;$sp<$p;$sp=$sp+1)
 {
  if($arr2[$st][0]==$arr1[$sp][0])
  {
   if($arr2[$st][1]!=$arr1[$sp][1])
   {
    $stat=1;
   }
  }
 }
}
if($stat==0)
{
echo "They match";
}
else
{
 echo "They dont match";
}
?>

Comment: Altough I apreciate your work, this doesn't do what I wanted in the first place though. I guess you're now comparing the strings? Sorry if I mislead you by saying I want to compare the two things. I wanted to compare the two arrays while I keep in mind the frequency of the letters apearing.

Comment: The frequencies are what I'm comparing.
The $arr1[$p][1] and $arr2[$q][1] parameters store the frequencies of the letters at the positions $arr1[$p][0] and $arr2[$q][0] respectively.

Comment: Could you explain then why the script still is saying it doesn't match tho? It should do, right?

Comment: It wont match..I dont think you get the concept of frequencies. 
b appears once in beer..thrice in the other string. I leave it to you to decide why it wont match

Comment: I still feel you havent got the concept of frequencies down..But I got what you meant..This should work fine   <?php $data = "beer"; $data2="rieebbb"; $p=0; $q=0; $stat=0; foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val) { $arr1[$p][0]=chr($i); $arr1[$p][1]=$val; $p=$p+1; } foreach (count_chars($data2, 1) as $j => $val2) { $arr2[$q][0]=chr($j); $arr2[$q][1]=$val2;  $q=$q+1; } for($st=0;$st<$q;$st=$st+1) { for($sp=0;$sp<$p;$sp=$sp+1) { if($arr2[$st][0]==$arr1[$sp][0]) { if($arr2[$st][1]<$arr1[$sp][1]) { $stat=1; } } } } if($stat==0) { echo "They match"; } else { echo "They dont match"; } ?>

Comment: @abhiii5459: Please edit your answer and add the code. It's impossible to read in the comments.